# Notification sound is too loud when listening to music with a headset

Tags: notifications, audio, 6.0-marshmallow

I'm using a Galaxy S6.  When I'm listening to music with my headphones plugged in, notifications come through startlingly loud.

I checked my sound settings, and I have the volume for notifications very low.  I verified the volume in `settings -> sounds and vibration -> volume`.  If I have my music playing the test feedback volume is super high even at my low setting.  But once the music is paused, the notification volume returns to its normal reasonable level.

**Why do my notifications use such a high volume to interrupt my music?  Is there a setting I'm overlooking to prevent notification volume from being boosted while music is playing?**  I'd prefer a built-in solution without external apps, but I'm willing to use reasonable add-ons to manage volume.

---

Note: I'm ok with the notification interrupting/dimming the music, but I don't want the volume of the notification to rupture my eardrums in an attempt to drown out the music.

Comment: What music player are you using?  I use poweramp (with my gain turned quite low) and with the 6.0 update I started noticing this behavior, but I tested what happened when I closed poweramp and the notification sound was what I would normally expect to hear.  I wonder if it's caused by the 6.0 update changing something and the music app(s) you (and I) are using not updating to account for it yet?

Comment: This happens with both Google Play Music and the built in Samsung Music applications.

Comment: I'm also getting this, with Microsoft Groove and Podbean. I believe the problem started when the phone (I have an S6 Edge) was updated with Marshmallow.

Answer (score -1):

The side volume buttons on your device can bring up four volume options by clicking the arrow. Try adjusting the notification setting and maybe even the system setting if that doesn't work. Easy listening my brother.

Comment: The questioner says they already set the notification volume as low as it will go.